# Can we mkdir + rename and remain atomic?

Tags: c++, c, unix, posix, atomic

I am designing a build system that needs to be careful about manipulating the filesystem in an atomic manner.

I have run into a situation where I have a temporary directory that contains files and now I want to move it to a more permanent home. I know how to [rename atomically](https://rcrowley.org/2010/01/06/things-unix-can-do-atomically.html), but this does not work if the full destination path does not exist. If I didn't care about being atomic, the answer would be a simple `mkdir -p ... && mv ...`. Is it possible to rename the temporary directory atomically in a way that will create the parent directories? I cannot do so ahead of time, because the parent directory names are computed.

This will be run inside of a [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) program, so something from the [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) ecosystem would be desirable, but it is trivial to call a command line program or C / C++ library to do the work.

**Example:**

```
/tmp/mytempbuild - a directory containing files
/myproject/build/dev/0.2.2 - the desired destination, whose parent may not exist
/myproject/build/master - an older, existing directory that must not be changed
```

Comment: Can't you just do the rename part on the top level destination directory?

Comment: Well I can't scan the filesystem to see which directories exist, as that breaks the atomicity. I also can't overwrite siblings which may exist from previous builds. I have updated the question to clarify the constraints of the problem.

Comment: You will need to do a mutex of some kind around the multiple filesystem operations.

Comment: If `/myproject/build/dev` doesn't exist, you should be able to `mkdir /myproject/build_tmp/$random`, then put everything under there (not worrying about atomicity for this part since your other processes don't read anything from there), then, after `/myproject/build_tmp/$random/0.2.2/...` is ready, `mv /myproject/build_tmp/$random /myproject/build/dev` and the whole thing appears atomically - any process looking in `build` will not see `dev` until the whole thing is moved into place. (Assuming `build` and `build_tmp` are on the same filesystem. If `build` is a mount point it'll be harder.)

Comment: I was thinking along similar lines. But I can't know `dev` doesn't exist until I try to put something in there. In between the time I've realized that (either by trying or checking with `stat`, etc) and then corrected for it, anything can happen. Creating the missing structure in the temporary space (or deciding which level of it to use) is only really possible as a second action after having read the state of the disk, thus opening the usual [can of worms](http://www.linuxsecurity.com/content/view/115462/151/).

Comment: OK, so first you pessimistically assume that it doesn't exist. Don't check. Just go ahead and build the tmp tree. Then do the rename. If `dev` does exist (either it always did or it was created while you were populating the tmp tree), the attempt to rename over an existing directory will fail with `EEXISTS`. If you get that error, you move down one level and try renaming *that* into place, leaving behind an empty `dev` in the tmp space. Repeat until you succeed or run out of directories, in which case you're trying to atomically replace a populated directory with another populated directory...

Comment: ...which isn't possible.